# Как обработать переход от NSMenuItem?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, menu

Делаю простеньков приложение для macOS. Накидал меню в storyboard с помощью `NSMenu` и `NSMenuItem`. Затем у одного из `NSMenuItem` установил переход (через контекстное меню, Triggered segues) на новый `NSViewController`. Аналогичные действия можно проворачивать и для кнопок, и для всего остального. Но суть в том, что перед показом данного `NSViewController` мне  ещё надо кое-что в нём настроить. Как мне получить конечный `NSViewController` перед переходом?
Меню в storyboard выглядит вот так (самый верхний уровень):

[image: Главное меню приложения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил данную проблему следующим образом:

Сделал segue между ViewController, с которого осуществляется переход, на тот, куда он осуществляется. Этот segue сделал просто связав мышкой сами контроллеры (вел не от какого-либо контрола или пункта меню). У segue сделал свой Identifier - MySegue.

Уже от конкретного пункта меню сделал action на свой FirstResponder, этот action предварительно описал в том ViewController, с которого происходит переход:

```
- (IBAction)onTransition:(id)sender
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:sender];
}
```

Затем в этом же VC переопределил метод prepareForSegue, в котором уже можно работать с контроллером, на который мы переходим:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
    DestinationViewController *dest = (DestinationViewController *)segue.destinationController;
    // Задаем нужные поля
    dest.field = self.field;
  }
}
```

Конкретно же переход от пункта меню сразу на контроллер отловить не получится, так как меню не привязано ни к какому окну и метод prepareForSegue:sender: переопределить негде.

Comment: Тут есть один нюанс - на storyboard данное меню располагается не на NSViewController, а внутри объекта NSApplication. Как мне в таком случае тянуть данный segue, если у меня по сути нет изначального NSViewController?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Немного не понял вас. По умолчанию меню и так не привязано ни к какому ViewController, и внутри объекта NSApplication точно быть не может. Пожалуйста, поясните, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: Добавил изображение в вопрос.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Как я уже сказал, я тяну action на FirstResponder, он у вас на картинке виден снизу, красный

Comment: С настройкой action проблем нет, проблема с segue - как мне её тянуть в данном случае (точнее откуда) ?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Работа с segue возможна только в контексте двух контроллеров. Если у вас нет первого, то реализуйте указанный мной Action в AppDelegate, инстанициируйте новый контроллер там и покажите его через showWindow. Тогда никакие segue не понадобятся.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58568/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-dmitry-serov).

Comment: Посмотрите чат пожалуйста.